# flutter: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, is-empty

I am calling web API and receiving the Profile model as a response. When I am using the below code then it is throwing me an error:

```
try{
   if(profile.message.isEmpty){
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/home");
   }else if(profile == null){
      _showDialog("Please check your internet connection");
   }else{
      _showDialog("Please enter valid credentials");
   }
}catch(exception){
   print(exception);
}
```

Comment: That's because `profile.message` returns `null`. You might want `if(profile?.message?.isEmpty ?? true)`

Comment: Thanks its working for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is because `profile.message` returns `null`. You might want

```
if(profile?.message?.isEmpty ?? true)
```

`?` prevents an error if the previous part of the expression results in `null` and `?? true` results in `true` if the previous part of the expression is `null` and therefore treats `== null` and `isEmpty` the same for the `if(...)` check.