# Firebase/Flutter : Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter

so I am trying to create collection with a document in firestore, from variables I collected in Form fiels, code goes:

```
onPressed:() async {
              await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection(_ICO).add({
                  "Company name": _compname,
              }).then((_){
                print("success!");
              });
```

and this is the error code I am getting:

**F/crash_dump32(18407): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 181: Permission denied
I/e.firebase_com(17852): Thread[5,tid=17868,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xe1a8d210,peer=0x13240228,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/e.firebase_com(17852):
I/e.firebase_com(17852): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
E/flutter (17852): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null.
E/flutter (17852): Receiver: null
E/flutter (17852): Tried calling: isNotEmpty**

I should also mention that I am logged in with user account while trying to run this code.

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777801/flutter-nosuchmethoderror-the-getter-isempty-was-called-on-null)

Comment: if the answer below solved your question mark it accepted as answer ;)

Comment: Neither of those solved my problem,was looking into that article already before, as I comented Moaid my rules were already true for everyone

Comment: There's really not enough code to know what's going on, but investigating `_ICO` and `_compname` may reveal something. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally found an answer to my question, it was really stupid mistake or rather 2...

1st:

```html
Widget _buildICO(){
  return TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'ICO'),
    validator: (String value){
      if (value.isEmpty){
        return 'ICO je potrebné';
      }
    },
    onSaved: (String value){
      ICO = value;
    },
  );

}
```

Well as you may have already see I have "onSaved" function there which I do not call when pressing the button therefore sending null values.

2nd:

Haven't created proper variable with the right features for this :

```html
Map<String , dynamic> data(){
    return{
   'compname': compname,
   'ICO': ICO,
    };
  }
```

My button now looks like:

```html
onPressed:() async {
                  if(!_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                    return;
                  }
                  _formKey.currentState.save();
                  firestore
                      .collection(ICO)
                      .doc(compname)
                      .set(data());
```

I found what was the problem after I got back to it and tried just writing a document into an empty collection and found out that my values returned as null (since u can not create a null collection but you can save null values into document),

Hope my question helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the rules so that the database is only readable/writeable by authenticated users:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

or

```
{ "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true, } }
```

to be always available , remember to change it in production

Go to database, next go to rules of your database , Change rules to true.

Comment: Since this is my testing project my database is accessible by everyone, not just users

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}